# ImGUI vs RmGUI technical comparison

Tags: user-interface, imgui, immediate-mode

I am trying to figure out what really Immediate Mode GUI is in opposite to Retained one.

As it is described in Dear ImGui docs (https://github.com/ocornut/imgui):
"An IMGUI tries to minimize superfluous state duplication, state synchronization and state retention from the user's point of view."

That's how I understand it right now.

Lets assume we got checkbox in our UI:

IMGUI: Checkbox is drawn with value that comes directly from data and on edit value goes back immediately to the data, which makes checkbox stateless.

RMGUI: Checkbox is an object with its own state 1/0 which comes from data on init and it keeps being updated in object, but does not get injected to the data immediately.

Is my thinking correct?
Could you please, give me some more examples of such comparison?

Best regards